# ORA-29280: invalid directory path

Tags: oracle, plsql

First I connect to SYS and did the following

1. Create a directory where your files will be uploaded

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY FILE_DIRR AS 'C:\EXCEL_FILES2';
   ```
2. Grant read, write permission to the database user

   ```
   GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY FILE_DIRR TO HRM;
   ```

In form write the code is:

```
declare
  file         utl_file.file_type;
  str         varchar2(500);
  v_item_id   number;
  v_item_name varchar2(500);
  p_dir       varchar2(500) := 'FILE_DIRR';
  p_file_name varchar2(500) := 'item_Sheet.xlsx';
  p_file_name varchar2(500) := 'item_Sheet.csv';
begin 
  file := utl_file.fopen(p_dir, p_file_name, 'r');

  for i in 1 .. 1 loop
    utl_file.get_line(fp, str);
  end loop;

  loop
    begin
      utl_file.get_line(file, str);
      v_item_id := substr(str, 1, instr(str, ',') - 1);
      str := substr(str, instr(str, ',') + 1);
      v_item_name := str;
  
      begin
        insert into items (item_id,item_name) values (v_item_id,v_item_name);
        commit;
      end;
    exception when no_data_found then
      exit;  
    end;
  end loop;

  utl_file.fclose(fp);
end;
```

I expected this code to run successfully

Comment: Is there a folder named `C:\EXCEL_FILES` on the database server? (Not your desktop.)

Answer (score 0):

The sintax to create Directory Object in Oracle is:

```sql
 CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] DirectoryObjectName AS 'Path';
```

In your case:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY FILE_DIRR AS 'C:\EXCEL_FILES2';
```

FILE_DIRR is Directory Object Name and the path is 'C:\EXCEL_FILES2'. The err message sugests that the path doesn't exist. For this to work you need to have access to the file system and to define correct path of existing folder.
Hope you did not think that the command would create a new directory in the file system.